# finding eigenvalues and vectors for a linear transformation over a infinite dimensional Vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

let $V$={$(x_1, x_2,...,x_n...)$}|$x_i$ are real numbers } under normal operations

and $T((x_1, x_2,...,x_n...))=(x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,...,(x_n)+(x_{n+1})...)$
Find 
$$T((x_1, x_2...,x_n,...))=\lambda((x_1, x_2...,x_n,...))$$

so so i start like 
$$(x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,...,x_n+x_{n+1}...)=(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2...,\lambda x_n...)$$

so $$ x_1 + x_2 = \lambda x_1 $$
.
.
.$$ x_n + x_{n+1} =\lambda x_n $$
.
.
.am i on the right track ?

Comment: Hint: consider two cases.  (1) If $\lambda=1$ then you can find specific values for $x_2,x_3,\ldots\,$.  (2) If $\lambda\ne1$ then you can find $x_2,x_3,\ldots$ in terms of $x_1$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the question. You're likely to get better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does is happens when you consider the followings vectors?
$$T(1,0,...,0,...)=?$$
$$T(0,1,...,0,...)=?$$
$$T(0,0,...,1,...)=?$$
Then you should be able to complete your task...